# How to render a Javascript and CSS for desktop devices only with client side solution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I already know that the feature detection in better approach than device detection. But in a responsive website project I'm using a Jquery plugin which improve the experience in desktop but not on Mobile and touch devices so I want to load some specific javascript and css file for Desktop browsers only.

For example below code I want to load for desktop only. I can't use any server side solution as it's a static page hosted on google drive.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
<script src="js/common.js"></script>

Desktop only css and js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css" />
<script src="js/desktop.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908406/conditionally-load-js-script-for-desktop-pc-not-touch-device-with-certain-widt

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Yepnope has been deprecated.

Comment: For CSS, I would suggest looking at Media Queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: @NormanBreau I know about that. In case of media queries it download the whole css too all devices.

Comment: @JitendraVyas I have read in some post that HTTP/2 downloads resources only if the media query is satisfied.

Comment: But on the client side, there is no **reliable** way to detecting if the user is on a desktop browser or a mobile browser. This is because browsers tend to lie with their user agent string, and users can usually change the user agent string that the browser gives out. Detecting screen resolution is not reliable as well as people can resize the browser window.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu ok but in my current question I want to detect devices by user agent not by screen resolution and dpi.

Comment: For example, my version of chrome by default has this `navigator.userAgent` value: `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36`. It mentions that it is Mozilla/Gecko, AppleWekit Safari, and Chrome.

Comment: If you really must do browser detection, this post in the MDN might help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent but like inside the article. It is probably a really bad idea. 9 times of 10, you can build your HTML and CSS in a way that it supports all kinds of resolutions, without having a performance problem.

Comment: Can we ask what the usability improvement is for desktop users? Depending what it is, feature detection may reveal what you need to know and verify you are applying to the right browsers.

Comment: The only use case I know for UA sniffing, is when the developer can't be bothered implementing a proper solution :)

Comment: @scunliffe I'm using this plugin and want to use it for desktop only and it can't be disabled for touch based high dpi devices. read this discussion here https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1285

Answer (score 0):

**First step: sniff the user agent**

You can use a library such as this - https://github.com/madferro/Sniff.js
Or develop your own solution. From MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

> In summary, we recommend looking for the string “Mobi” anywhere in the
>   User Agent to detect a mobile device.

**Second step: load your resources on the fly**

Again, you can do it yourself, by writing the script and style tags ([`document.createElement('script')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)), or you could use a library:

- YepNope: http://yepnopejs.com/
- RequireJs http://requirejs.org/
- LABjs: https://github.com/getify/LABjs
- headjs: https://github.com/headjs/headjs

---

Could end up looking similar to this (untested):

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
<script src="js/common.js"></script>
<script src="js/sniff.js"></script>

<script>
    if(!sniff.mobile){
        var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
        scriptTag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        scriptTag.setAttribute("src", "js/desktop.js");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);

        var linkTag = document.createElement('link');
        linkTag.setAttribute("type","text/css");
        linkTag.setAttribute("href", "css/desktop.css");
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(linkTag);
</script>    
</head>
```